# With the descent of Newtonian mechanics is Newton's third law still valid?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, momentum, conservation-laws, standard-model

Or more specifically, with the standard model, quantum theory and other advances in physics, all those experiments in CERN and other accelerators, was there any occurrence where this law was violated? Or would this even be a law and possibly be out of context?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "descent of classical physics". Newton is as valid as it always was and always will be. Physics is a series of approximations. An approximation doesn't lose its value when a new approximation for a _different_ case is discovered.

Comment: Hello. I think the title is a little "heavy", so you might want to change the "descent" part, since it' s not a correct statement from all different points of view. Otherwise, this could be a usual question. On the context of violation, one could think of Electrodynamics. To conserve momentum there, you need to treat the theory as what it is: a field theory, thus attributing the fields themeselves with momentum and energy and whatever. So, proceeding to a "generalization", if I may, of a change of view, you maintain the 3Law. John Rennie's answer points toward another more general treatment.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's third law is a statement that momentum is conserved, so it is equivalent to the law of conservation of momentum. Conservation of momentum follows from a fundamental symmetry (of the action) called space shift symmetry and as far as we know this applies to all our physical theories.

So Newton's law is still valid but has to be treated with some care in theories like general relativity where conservation of momentum still applies but is a lot more complicated.